# I want different users to have different cache

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

Question, for those who have worked with the fastapi-cache2 library:

I want different users to have a different cache, so that when the user changes, the data is first re-entered into the cache.

To do this, I rewrote the key generator so that it generates a key based on the user id:

```
def key_builder(
    func,
    namespace: str = "",
    *args,
    **kwargs,
):
    user_id = get_user_id(kwargs)
    cache_key = f"{user_id}:{settings.cache_key_prefix}:{func.__module__}:{func.__name__}:{args}:{kwargs}"
    return cache_key
```

It generates the key correctly.

Added a router function in which I clear all the user's keys:

```
async def clear_all_users_keys(user_id: int):
    redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://redis:6379", encoding="utf8")
    keys = await redis.keys(f"{user_id}*")
    if keys:
        for key in keys:
            await FastAPICache.clear(key=key)
        await redis.delete(*keys)
        await redis.close()
```

Inside the radish, all the keys are cleaned:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty array)
```

But after all these operations, the router is still cached for another 60 seconds. When I changing the user, the data is correspondingly old, what could be the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `redis.keys(f"{user_id}*")` wouldn't this also match all user ids with the same prefix? So if you're user_id: 1, the cache for 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, etc. would also be removed?) What does you cache for the route look like? How are you initializing fastapi-cache2?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?